# tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: doesn't get called when deselecting a row when using setAllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios5

I am using `setAllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` to allow for selecting of multiple rows when in editing mode. I want to know when a row is selected, so I use `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` which works fine.

But, I would like to know when one of those rows is deselected, but `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` doesn't get called when doing that. Is there any way to know when a row has been un/deselected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [*UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you will find a method named [`tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3adidDeselectRowAtIndexPath%3a).

Comment: Wow I am dumb. I wasn't looking in the delegate reference for some reason so I didn't spot it. Thanks!